# slider customization in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, slider

I am trying to customize s slider. The default slider is like the one in first image. The knob/thumb is the same height as slider bar, and it's far left (or right) position is still in the slider bar. I would like to customize knob x position to be the knobImage.x/2. Also, is it possible to lower the y position of knob? So far I have used a very tall and transparent knob, with the knoB image at the bottom. That gives the illusion of different y value but this is hard to maintain code. So how does one customize slider in libgdx?

[image]

Comment: did you try to get the slider drawable and add some ofset? Haven't tried anything like that but it meight work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you further explain?

Comment: Oh and I also tried adding some transparency to the left and right of slider background. veeery bad code, but with thousands repetitions I could get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the padding of the two drawables to adjust them. Let's assume your texture regions are named `blueBg` and `redKnob`.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable {
    paddedBlueBg: { region: blueBg, leftWidth: -10, rightWidth: -10, bottomHeight: -10},
    paddedRedKnob: { region: redKnob, topHeight: -20 },
},
```

Negative padding will allow the knob to overhang the edges. I put -10, but you should use whatever half the width of your slider is.

For the vertical padding values, you may need to tweak the two opposing values to get what you want.

The negative padding makes the slider bigger than the space it takes up in your layout, so if you're using it in a table, you will want to pad the cell by at least the amounts of your negative padding in the style.

Comment: thanks for taking your time. Sorry, but where should I put this code?

Comment: In the Json file that defines your skin. Make sure to read the documentation on customizing a skin with Json.

Comment: But how to do it programmatically?

Comment: @Crigges `leftWidth`, `rightWidth`, etc. are public member fields of a TextureRegionDrawable object so you can set them in your code. In my opinion, creating a skin programmatically instead of using JSON is a massive waste of time. Especially now that in the latest release of LibGDX, the JSON skins support cascading styles and you don't have to type the fully qualified class names. Of course, there will be exceptions if your styles are not static.

Comment: Tried that but without success. Using the `setRightWidth` and `setLeftWidth` function has not effect when used on the knob. And when used on the background, I still can't get the desired result. I tested tons of diferent values. https://pastebin.com/kBHqctjF